# wordpress alchemy put custom metabox on certain page only

Tags: metabox, pages, homepage

I want to put the custom metabox I have only on the home page but I am not sure how to go about doing this. I am using the following to add the custom meta box to all the pages. How would I select just the home page, or home.php template or that ID. I am really just not sure of the syntax.

```
<?php
$custom_mb = new WPAlchemy_MetaBox(array
(
    'id' => '_custom_meta',
    'title' => 'Add images to home page slider',
    'template' => get_stylesheet_directory() . '/metaboxes/custom-meta.php',
    'types' => array('page'),
));
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new WPAlchemy_MetaBox(array
(
    'id' => '_custom_meta',
    'title' => 'My Custom Meta',
    'template' => STYLESHEETPATH . '/custom/meta.php',
    'exclude_template' => 'product.php'
));
```

the 'exclude_template' would work for excluding the one's you didn't want.

```
new WPAlchemy_MetaBox(array
(
    'id' => '_custom_meta',
    'title' => 'My Custom Meta',
    'template' => STYLESHEETPATH . '/custom/meta.php',
    'include_template' => array('product.php','press.php') // use an array for multiple items
    // 'include_template' => 'product.php,press.php' // comma separated lists work too
));
```

including works the same.

Here's how you'd include only by post ID (Which if you're designing this for a client I wouldn't do they tend to break the Post ID's by midweek).

```
'include_post_id' => 97
```

Here's a link: http://www.farinspace.com/wpalchemy-metabox/#filter